# Has the minimum reputation to answer on Meta changed?

Tags: support, meta, new-users, stack-overflow-for-teams, privileges

Has the minimum reputation required to participate in meta been reduced?

I have just seen an answer from a user with only 1 reputation point. No, they are not suspended. Since it's not a question the usual "can post a question about their own question" spiel does not apply.

> [image: answer by a user with 1 reputation point]

Is meta open for all now? Or have I missed something with this [profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12364410/jamie23)?

The help-centre still [says 5 points are required](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aha, apparently there is no reputation requirement for users who are in a Team to post questions and answers, as users may be required to post [stack-overflow-for-teams](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-for-teams) bug reports or support questions on Meta.

Comment: Mystery solved! Being you the answerer, I'm a bit disappointed that it didn't involve a userscript. ;)